# Python 3 - string to list (I know it has been asked but I can't get anything to work)

Tags: python-3.x

I have an assignment, similar to scrabble.  I have to check if a subset is in the set.  can only use a letter once.  so if subset has 2t and the set has 1t it is false.
My problem is, I used 2 inputs to allow people to enter the subset and set, but that create a string no breaks between the letters which mean split or list won't create a LIST with individual letters. (at least I can't find any way.)
My plan was something like

```
wordset = word.lower().split()
subset = letters.lower()
for i in range(len(subset)):
    if i in subset and in set:
        set.remove(i)
```

I know that properly won't work but until I can get it into a list or someone gives me a hint how to do it with string I can't start testing it.  Sorry for so much writing.

Comment: Are you not allowed to use the `set` functionality?

Comment: still give all the letters as 1 item.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to get a list of characters in a given string you can use a list comprehension:

```
characters = [x for x in some_string]
```

Comment: wordset = word.lower().split()
subset = letters.lower()
characters = [x for x in wordset]
print(characters)   output ['afsd']

Comment: Remove the .split() call on the wordset

Comment: I changing tack, has any one got a suggestion if I don't use input and create the list of letters and a list of words how would I get it to select the word with most of the letters in it.

Comment: Thank you ExhoAR22, it is the little things that get me stuck